# Get list comprehension object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm committing a crime in python on purpose. This is a bad way of doing this.
The GOAL here is cursed code. All on one line.

I have basically whats below

```
with open("file") as f:
    [int(x) for x in [y for y in f.read().split()]
```

I cannot use

```
with open("file") as f:
    a = f.read().split()
    [x for x in [(a[i-1, e]) for i, e in enumerate(a) if i > 0] ...]
```

because the goal is to have this in one line (aside from the with open)

I would like to return from the original object the current element and either the previous one or the next one.

To illustrate it clearly.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

After the illegal code would return

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, ?)]
```

So again the focus here is not production code. This is purely to see how much we can abuse the language.

So far I've found https://code.activestate.com/recipes/204297/ which references the use of local in python2, after mucking around with it I found that the interface for it is a little different.
I've been able to get the object in memory but I dont know how to actually use this object now that I have it.

```
local()['.0']
```

Most attributes seem to be missing, no __self__ to call.

Please share your most cursed ideas for this.

Comment: @mkrieger1. The problem is that they're two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would use [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on the generator for something like this:

```
from itertools import tee, islice

with open("file") as f:
    a, b = tee(f.read().split())
    b = islice(b, 1, None)
    list(zip(a, b))
```

You can convert this into a one-liner using (abusing) the [walrus operator (`:=`)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
list(zip((k := tee(f.read().split()))[0], islice(k[1], 1, None)))
```

The result is

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

If you want the last element to be padded, use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import tee, islice, zip_longest
...
    list(zip_longest((k := tee(f.read().split()))[0], islice(k[1], 1, None), fillvalue='?'))
```

The result in this case is

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, '?')]
```

The nice thing about using iterators rather than lists this way is that while `f.read().split()` is a sequence of known length, the `tee` and `islice` will work on any iterable, even if the length is unknown.

Comment: I ended up using a mildly modified version of this, Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Grey. How did you modify it?

Comment: Since this is all being done in one line in a list comp we cant use the walrus operator. BUT i realized I can re read the data source multiple times which added to the cursed nature of the code.
Culminating with `len([a for a, b in list(zip(*[islice(open(input_file_path, "r").read().split(), x, None) for x in range(2)])) if int(b) > int(a)])`

This is all for advent of code, above is the solution for part 1 of day 1. part 2 is a bit too messy to be put in a comment.

Comment: Pastebin exists... Here's part 2!
https://pastebin.com/SnXZ77sR

Comment: @Grey. Gotcha. So cursed == both illegible and inefficient, but still somehow functioning. That actually makes sense. I was just focusing on getting a one-liner, which is usually bad enough.